# IBM Mobilefirst 8.0 session persistence error

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

Setup:

- 2 HTTP Servers
- 1 Load Balancer between 2 HTTP server and 2 MobileFirst servers
- 2 MobileFirst server 8.0 s on Liberty Farm 8.5.5
- IBM DB2

i am facing an issue with session affinity during mobilefirst server failover. when it failed over to other server, the console says the session has expired.

i followed the below link to configure the session persistence for Liberty but the procedure is not clear. i created sessions database but it doesn't create any table under that.

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_admin_session_persistence.html

the web plugin config.xml files is configured to point so it's like HTTP server >  LB > mobilefirst servers.

Comment: Sounds like you should open a PMR to the liberty team.

Comment: Check the message.log file if you have any errors during server startup.